# Xcode 4.3 installaiton error in Mac OS X 10.7.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-lion, xcode4.3

We have bought a new iMac with `Mac Os X 10.7.3 Lion` version. I have tried to install the `Xcode 4.3` from Applications. But when i have tried to install the Xcode it is showing `"A Unknown error occurred. See the install log for more details"`. But i don't have any error logs in `install.log file`. I found the error in `all messages.log file`. I can't understand what is wrong. I have mentioned the error log here,

```
com.apple.SecurityServer: Failed to authorize right 'system.install.app-store-software' by client '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/installd' [744] for authorization created by '/Applications/Xcode.app' [735]
```

Can anyone please help to install the Xcode 4.3 and go ahead to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than trying to fix this by re-installing etc you might as well go straight to the current version: Xcode 4.4.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Xcode 4.4 is not support in 10.7.3 Lion right. Xcode 4.4 for mountain lion os. I have tried that. Thanks.

Comment: Xcode 4.4 only requires Lion - I'm using it right now on OS X 10.7.4.

Comment: @PaulR when i have tried to install Xcode 4.4 it warned me to install Mountain lion os. Thats why i have told you. Don't mistaken me. Also i have solved the issue from Mr.Yuvaraj's Answer. Thanks for your helping hand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply right click and show content -> Resource -> Package
manually install the mobile device and we are all set :)